# When is $\mathbb Z[\zeta_p]$ a free module over its quadratic subring?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory

There is a unique quadratic subfield $K=\mathbb Q(\sqrt{p^*})$ in $\mathbb Q(\zeta_p)$ ($p>2$), when is $\mathbb Z[\zeta_p]$ a free $O_K$ module?

Comment: None of the arguments [there](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/gradnumthy/notfree.pdf) address your case $L/K/\mathbb{Q}$ cyclic. It says there are always a fractional ideal of $O_K$ and $\beta_j \in O_L$ such that $O_L =  \beta_1\mathfrak{a}\oplus  \beta_2 O_K \oplus \ldots \oplus \beta_r O_K $ with $r = [L:K]$, so the problem is to find when $\mathfrak{a}$ is principal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's always free. An $O_K$-basis is provided by $\zeta_p^i$ for $1\le i\le (p-1)/2$.

Let $\delta=\sum_i \zeta_p^i$ where $i$ runs over the squares in ${\bf F}_p^*$.
Then $O_K={\bf Z}[\delta]={\bf Z}+\delta{\bf Z}$. 
Saying that $\zeta_p^i$ with $1\le i\le (p-1)/2$ is an $O_K$-basis of ${\bf Z}[\zeta_p]$  is equivalent to saying that  the elements $\zeta_p^i$ with $1\le i\le (p-1)/2$ together with the elements $\delta\zeta_p^i$ with $1\le i\le (p-1)/2$ are a ${\bf Z}$-basis of ${\bf Z}[\zeta_p]$.

The $\bf Z$-span of these elements is contained in ${\bf Z}[\zeta_p]$. So, it suffices to show that the index is $1$. This can be done by computing the determinant of the matrix whose columns are the conjugates of 
the elements $\zeta_p^i$ and $\delta\zeta_p^i$ with $1\le i\le (p-1)/2$ and comparing it with the determinant of the matrix whose columns are the conjugates of 
the elements $\zeta_p^i$ with $1\le i\le p-1$.

Comment: How do you see $O_K=Z[\delta]$?

Comment: Let $\bar\delta$ denote $\sum_i\zeta_p^i$ where $i$ runs over the non-squares. Then $\delta+\bar\delta=-1$, while $\delta-\bar\delta=\tau$, where $\tau$ is the Gaussian sum associated to the quadratic character mod $p$. By a classical computation with the Gaussian sum, $\delta$ satisfies the quadratic equation $\delta^2+\delta+(1-p^*)/4=0$.

Comment: Thank you, I don't know whether the computation works, could you provide some details?  In the paper "J.-P. Serre, Exemples de variétés projectives conjuguées non homéomorphes, C. R. Acad. Sci. Paris 258 (1964), 4194-4196 (Online at https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k4011c/f1832.item), lemma $1$ about the freeness is proved under a condition..

Comment: I saw the paper and the proof. Much cleaner than mine! What condition you are refering to?

Comment: He assume the class number is odd, so $s^2=1$ implies $s=1$ in the class group.

Comment: I don't think so. The class number is automatically odd. But in Serre's note the prime $p$ is congruent to $3$ mod $4$.

Comment: However, Serre's Lemme 1 is also correct for $p\equiv 1$ mod $4$, I think. So the answer to your original question is right there.